WearOs, uninstalling and reinstalling my app, it does not ask for permissions again
I am developing an app for Samsung Watch 6 (WearOS), based on the Sample Excercise app.
I installed it first time, it asked for all the permissions. Then I uninstalled it and installed it again and it did not ask for any permissions. I even restarted the watch, and then installed, it still does not ask for permissions.
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Bind to our service. Views will only update once we are connected to it.
        ExerciseService.bindService(requireContext().applicationContext, serviceConnection)
        bindViewsToService()

        binding.startButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkNotNull(serviceConnection.exerciseService) {
                "Failed to achieve ExerciseService instance"
            }.startExercise()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.exerciseFragment)
        }
        // Check permissions first.
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking permissions")
        permissionLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
    }

What is going on ? If I go to settings > Apps > myApp > Permission, I see no permissions allowed. When I allow all, and start the app, it still says Missing Permission.

I placed a beakpoint at permissionLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) and then let it run, I saw that the app then asked for permissions. So I added a delay to it like this
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(1000) {
            permissionLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
        }

and the app was now asking for permissions fine.
